# Magento 2 contributing tests to the new MFTF

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, core, testing, magento2.3

I would like to know if it's possible to contribute tests to the new MFTF framework. In the documentation it talks about contributing to the MFTF core itself, but not how to contribute tests for it, which are located outside the MFTF repository.

Also, I know the Magento team is working on allot of new tests right now, is there some place where I can see what tests are being worked on?